# "For me" — necessary or not?

Tags: ellipsis

> He works too slowly(for me)to be much use to me.

Can (for me)It  be omitted, (I think It can be omitted because "to me" give that information.

Comment: It *must* be omitted. "...for me to be of much use to me" makes no sense.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why (He spoke too quickly **for me** to understand.) this is correct?

Comment: That would be equivalent to rephrasing your sentence as "He works too slowly for me to appreciate him."

Comment: _He spoke too quickly for me to understand_. The desired result was that _I understood him_ In _He works too slowly to be of much use to me_, the desired result was that _he was useful to me_, not that _I was useful [to myself]_. Do you see how the two expressions are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He works too slowly (for me) to be [of] much use to me.

I have added *of*.

The preposition phrase *for me* should be omitted:

> He works too slowly to be of much use to me.

Having *for me* could be possible in a situation where you have a worker serving several supervisors.  This worker is not always slow; he is slow only when he is doing your projects.  Your example could be read as

> [He works too slowly **for me**] to be of much use to me.
> The other supervisors can have him.

Even in such a situation, we should still omit that preposition phrase, to make the sentence less clumsy and avoid having it read as

> [He works too slowly] [for me to be of much use to me].